# How to do decimal precision in Spring Data Jpa @Query Annotation

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do the following query in the query annotation. I am using postgresSQL. However if I use "::numeric(10, 2)" in the query then I got syntax error at or near ":". But if I remove "::numeric(10, 2)" this, it works fine.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT AVG(feedback_rating)::numeric(10, 2) FROM app_customer_feedback WHERE " +
        "created_date >= to_timestamp(:dateFrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND " +
        "created_date < to_timestamp(:dateTo, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')", nativeQuery = true)
Double getAverageByDateRange(@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") String dateTo);
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What Database engine?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I am using postgresSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colons need to be escaped!

**Solution 1: escape colons**

Every `:` needs to be replaced by `\\:`

```java
AVG(feedback_rating)\\:\\:numeric(10, 2)
```

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT AVG(feedback_rating)\\:\\:numeric(10, 2) FROM app_customer_feedback WHERE " +
        "created_date >= to_timestamp(:dateFrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND " +
        "created_date < to_timestamp(:dateTo, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')", nativeQuery = true)
Double getAverageByDateRange(@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") String dateTo);
```

**Solution 2: double colons**

Every `:` needs to be replaced by double colons `::`

```java
AVG(feedback_rating)::::numeric(10, 2)
```

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT AVG(feedback_rating)::::numeric(10, 2) FROM app_customer_feedback WHERE " +
        "created_date >= to_timestamp(:dateFrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND " +
        "created_date < to_timestamp(:dateTo, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')", nativeQuery = true)
Double getAverageByDateRange(@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") String dateTo);
```

**Solution 3: use [Cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createcast.html) instead of colons**

```java
cast(AVG(feedback_rating) as numeric(10, 2))
```

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT cast(AVG(feedback_rating) as numeric(10, 2)) FROM app_customer_feedback WHERE " +
        "created_date >= to_timestamp(:dateFrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND " +
        "created_date < to_timestamp(:dateTo, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')", nativeQuery = true)
Double getAverageByDateRange(@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") String dateTo);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Didn't know about the cast and double colons for escaping. However I tried with 1 backslash before asking and now I know I need to put 2 instead of 1. Anyway all the methods worked fine.